# View CSS When Using Sass And Sourcemaps

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

When Using Sourcemaps with Sass in Chrome I can Cmd-Click on a link in the Styles panel to jump to the original Sass from Dev Tools.

But is there a way to jump to the generated CSS as well?

Comment: Just clicking usually works.

Comment: @Paulie_D Clicking will take you to the Sass source. I want to know if there is also a way to click through to the generated CSS as you would do if source-maps weren't enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in chrome.
You can however do that in Firefox (developer edition)